rotary phase converter
I'm having issues with a 10 hp motor for a rotary phase converter. There were no labels on the motor wires, so I had to use this VIDEO to help me identify them, assuming that is the correct winding configuration of this motor. I am able to spin the motor up to about 1000 RPM, then I run over and flip on the 30 amp breaker, the motor buzzes then throws the breaker off. I've tried rotating it the other way and it still does the same thing. Out of curiosity, I spun up the motor and read zero volts across the leads. Shouldn't it read something? When I was pairing up the pairs of coils to the 3 wire coil, I had no issues locating what is what, using the same testing methods that the guy in the video explained. So I am stumped on this one.


You are connecting 240V single phase, to two of the legs of a 200V three phase motor

This is the direction I'm going with it: https://rapidfabtech.com/FitchWConverter.pdf There should be enough of a ghost leg to get it moving once I spin it up and add juice.

(What are you trying to achieve connecting the machine as depicted?) For an idea how to use it as a single-phase motor (a bit big for that - the "operational" capacitor would need to be on the order of .5 mF for about 5 hp, the motor manufacturer won't recommend it, your distribution network operator won't like it), see second.wiki on "Steinmetzschaltung".

I was able to get the motor running by reversing each of the paired legs. That confuses me as to why because I followed the video to the letter. Because it's missing a starting capacitor, I had to use a grinder, rubbing up against the pulley to get it spinning fast enough that the motor would run when the power was turned on. My initial voltage reads were 214, 205 and 240. With 240 mfd caps, I got two legs at 240vac.. I ran out of caps, so off to the restore.
